# Object across web methods + java

Tags: java, web-services

I am using a Java Web Service for

```
@WebService()
public class myWebService {

    /**
     * Web service operation
     */
    MyClass Obj ;

    @WebMethod(operationName = "webmethod1")
    @Oneway
    public void webmethod1(@WebParam(name = "serailNo") String serailNo) {

        obj = new MyClass();
        //do some operations on obj;

    }

    /**
     * Web service operation
     */
    @WebMethod(operationName = "webmethod2")
    public void webmethod2() {

        //do some operations on obj after doing intial operations in web method1

    }
}
```

I am unable to access obj in webmethod2. It is getting a null pointer exception.
As a detail : I want to create a object . That object should be accessed across all web methods. In such a way webmethod1 will do intial operations on obj and followed web method2 will use the same obj. 
How can i achieve this

Comment: I would suggest changing to method1 to return the object and sending that object in method2. Nullpointer is obviously there because there is not state at server. Which you can maintain needed be but that a bigger fish to fry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you are getting a nullpointer is because the webservice is not stateful, i.e the object does **not** exist during the second call. It is possible to create a stateful webservice but that depends on the kind of webservice and server your running it on...

As npinti mentioned you could send the object along with the service. Although that might not be favorable, e.g if the object is big.

You could create a local cache on the server containing all the created objects by and mapping them with the serialNo.

Comment: you mean "the object does NOT exist"

Comment: how could i create a cache stuff?

Comment: any clue on procedure to create stateful ws

Comment: with ejb3 you can create Singleton beans which work great as caches. With proper READ/WRITE configurations you can also make sure they they handle multiple threads insted of one at a time(which is the default).

Comment: @Sridhar Stateful ws is tricker as it depends on the type of ws and the server your running on... probably best to google "stateful webservice <your-server>"

Answer (score 1):

If you are creating a brand new object, what you could do, would be to make your `webmethod1` return whatever object it creates, and then, make `webmethod2` take that same object as a parameter.

Another option would be to make `webmethod2` take in the `serialNo` parameter and check that the `obj` variable is not null. If it is, it will call `webmethod1` by passing it that same serial number, and create the object so that it has something to work on.